# py2exe setup.py not working

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, python-3.4, py2exe

I have an small code that uses pandas and sqlalchemy and is declared in my main.py as:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

this is my complete setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob

data_files = [("Microsoft.VC90.CRT", glob(r'C:\Users\Flavio\Documents\Python_dll\*.*'))]

opts = {
    "py2exe": {
        "packages": ["pandas", "sqlalchemy"]
    }
}

setup(
    data_files=data_files,
    options = opts,
    console=['main.py']
)
```

And I'm using this command in terminal:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

But when I run main.exe it's open the terminal start to execute code and suddenly close window.

when I run over terminal it's the error:

```
C:\Users\Flavio\Documents\python\python\untitled\dist>main.exe
Please add a valid tradefile date as yyyymmdd: 20150914
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Flavio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.p
y", line 386, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Flavio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies
.py", line 75, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "C:\Users\Flavio\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\connectors\pyodbc
.py", line 51, in dbapi
    return __import__('pyodbc')
ImportError: No module named 'pyodbc'
```

Answer (score 0):

without know what your program does 
I would try the following 1st
open a command window and run your .exe from there
The window will not close and any error messages (if any) will be displayed